# Not getting the req.user object using express-jwt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, express-jwt

Here is my setup with `express-jwt`:

```js
exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
   secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
   algorithms: ["HS256"], 
   userProperty: "auth"
 });
```

I am using it access a secret route for testing but however i am not getting the `req.user` property in my route here. It results in a empty object(undefined).

```js
router.get("/secret",requireSignin,(req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: req.user,
    });
});
```

I am using Postman to test and sending the token with the authorization header as a bearer token.

Comment: is that a complete code of `requireSignin ` middleware?

Answer (score 5):

I also got stuck with this exercise. To solve the problem use req.auth instead like this:

```
router.get("/secret",requireSignin,(req, res) => {
    res.json({
        user: req.auth,
    });
   
});
```

I hope it is useful. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `requestProperty` determine where the decoded token is going to be stored, with `express-jwt` version < 6, it was `user` by default and now it's `auth`. If you want `req.user` to not be undefined try:

```js
import { expressjwt } from 'express-jwt';

exports.requireSignin = expressjwt({
   secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
   algorithms: ["HS256"], 
   requestProperty: "user",
 });
```

Or use `req.auth` instead of `req.user` with your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are not verifying/decoding your JWT token from request, once decoded, assign it `req` object and call `next()`

```js
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports.requireSignin = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization

  if (!token) {
    res.status(400).json({ status: false, message: 'Token required' })
  }

  JWT.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`JWT: ${err.message}`)
      return res
        .status(401)
        .json({ status: false, error: 'Token is not valid' })
    }
    req.user = decoded
    next()
  })
}
```

ohhhh, you're using `express-jwt` package. I didn't see at first my answer is general with how to get token payload object in the `req`. Hope it can help someone in future.